# How do I fix this warning - "control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"

Tags: c++

During compiling, it shows this warning - control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]. I googled and found that this warning shows when you don't return anything in the function. But I couldn't figure out where's the error in my code.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int findUnique(int *a, int n){
    sort(a, a+n);
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
            i += 2;
        }
        else{
            return a[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--){

        int size;
        cin >> size;
        int *input = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            cin >> input[i];
        }

        cout << findUnique(input, size) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read and explain your code to a [rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Specifically, when you are returning, and under what conditions you return.

Comment: What does `findUnique` return if the `while` exits without doing the `return` ?

Comment: The loop may also access `input` out of bounds. If `i = n -1` the loop will take a turn and then you access `a[n]` (in `a[i+1]`) which makes the program have _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know why this warning is shown to understand what to do about it, this warning is shown when your function has a return type but you haven't returned value from one or more exit points of a function. Now see in your function, you return `a[i]` but consider a situation where your code doesn't go in the `else` block at all. So after coming out of the `while` block. There is no `return` statement therefore compiler is throwing `control reaches the end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns nothing in case when the array does not contain a unique number or when the parameter `n` is equal to `0`.

So the compiler issues the warning message.

Moreover the while loop can invoke undefined behavior when `i` is equal to `n-1` due to using a non-existent element with the index `n` in this if statement

```
    if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
```

Also there is a logical error. The if statement

```
    if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
        i += 2;
    }
    else{
        return a[i];
    }
```

does not guarantee that indeed a unique number will be returned.

Using your approach when it is allowed to change the original array by calling the algorithm `std::sort` the function can be defined for example the following way

```
size_t findUnique( int *a, size_t n )
{
    std::sort( a, a + n );

    size_t i = 0;

    bool unique = false;

    while ( !unique && i != n )
    {
        size_t j = i++;

        while ( i != n && a[i] == a[j] ) i++;

        unique = i - j == 1;
    }

    return unique ? i - 1 : i;
}
```

And in main the function can be called like

```
size_t pos = findUnique(input, size);

if ( pos != size )
{ 
   cout << input[pos] << endl;
}
else
{
    // output a message that there is no unique number
}
```

Pay attention to that your program produces multiple memory leaks. You need to free the allocated memory in each iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in the function `findUnique` This function is supposed to return `int` no matter what although in your code you are returning an integer only under certain conditions

Here is a possible fix:

```
// return true if unique number found
// return false otherwise
bool findUnique(int *a, int n, int *unique){
    sort(a, a+n);
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
            i += 2;
        }
        else{
            *unique = a[i];
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then in the `main` something like that:

```
int unique;
bool uniqueFound = findUnique(input, size &unique);
if (uniqueFound == true)
    cout << unique << endl;
else
    cout << "No unique number found" << endl;
```